# Select one record from LAG Query

Tags: sql-server, query

I'm having difficulty getting data from a query using the LAG method. The issue is that I only need one record from the entire set pulled down, but when I filter out that record in the WHERE clause it prevents the LAG method from using the entire dataset for its comparisons, and just returns NULL. For example, I have this set of records in my DB:

[image: Dataset]

All I want is the previous status to "Finished". But when I run this query, it only returns NULL because there is only one record the LAG method is working with:

```
SELECT
    s.StatusName, LAG(s.StatusName) OVER (ORDER BY cs.CustomerId, cs.CustomerStatusId) as PreviousStatus
FROM 
    #CustomerStatus as cs
    left join #Status as s on s.StatusId = cs.StatusId 
WHERE 
    cs.StatusId = 3 

ORDER BY
    cs.CustomerStatusId
```

If I remove the WHERE clause, it pulls the dataset below correctly, but I only want the third record:

[image: Dataset2]

Is there a way for me to grab only that one record from the results?

If you would like to work with my sample data, here is the Rexter link:

[Rexter - LAG](https://rextester.com/ZBSB6302)

Comment: What if there are two rows with `status = 'Finished'`? What should be returned then?

Comment: Is your question about returning this result (Finished) for every CustomerID? That is, the Query really is returning all the customers that have finished “jobs”

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is happening because of the row being filtered before the `LAG()` function executes, making it unable to get the previous results.

To work around this, we could use a CTE or a subquery to execute the `LAG()` function before applying the filter.

**Using a CTE**

```
;WITH CTE  AS
(
SELECT
    s.StatusName, LAG(s.StatusName) OVER (ORDER BY cs.CustomerId, cs.CustomerStatusId) as PreviousStatus, cs.StatusId,cs.CustomerStatusId
FROM 
    #CustomerStatus as cs
    left join #Status as s on s.StatusId = cs.StatusId 
) 
SELECT StatusName ,PreviousStatus
FROM CTE
WHERE 
StatusId = 3 
ORDER BY
    CustomerStatusId;
```

**Result**

```
StatusName  PreviousStatus
Finished    Started
```

[Rextester](https://rextester.com/BUJPV26554)

**With a subquery**

```
SELECT outerquery.StatusName ,outerquery.PreviousStatus
FROM (    
    SELECT
    s.StatusName, LAG(s.StatusName) OVER (ORDER BY cs.CustomerId, cs.CustomerStatusId) as PreviousStatus, cs.StatusId,cs.CustomerStatusId
    FROM 
    #CustomerStatus as cs
    left join #Status as s on s.StatusId = cs.StatusId 
     ) as outerquery
WHERE 
outerquery.StatusId = 3 
ORDER BY
    outerquery.CustomerStatusId;
```

**Result**

```
StatusName  PreviousStatus
Finished    Started
```

[Rextester](https://rextester.com/XHSV35456)

The `ORDER BY CustomerStatusId;` might not be needed if you only need one record

Comment: Is there any way to use this as a subquery in a larger query?

Comment: @Vandel212 I added a subquery to the answer, is that what you needed?

Comment: Thank you, I'll definitely look into it, and let you know. Some other things came up, and I had to put this on the back burner for now. Again, thank you for your help.

Comment: @Vandelt not a problem, looking forward to hearing if it worked :).

Comment: @Vandel212 awesome, glad it helped!